# php artisan key:generate - cache directory must be present and writable

Tags: php, laravel, composer, artisan

Un saludo stackoverflowers

He clonado el proyecto, y al generar la clave con `php artisan key:generate`, me genera el mensaje `cache directory must be present and writable` y no genera el codigo que se necesita.

Como podria solucionar este problema?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Un saludo.
Despues de buscar por internet sin resultados, publique la pregunta, luego un colega (Christian Rivas ) me dio la solucion.

Limpiar cache `php artisan cache:clear` (esto no funciono), luego **eliminar carpeta de Bootstrap** (tener copia de los archivos y carpetas internas). Siguiente paso es crear carpeta con cada uno de los archivos y carpetas internos, ahora para terminar vamos a ejecutar `php artisan key:generate`

Y eso es todo, se genera la clave con exito.

Muchas gracias.